# Finding combinations in a set of numbers efficiently

Tags: java, combinations, memory-efficient

I am currently working on a java project, and I need one of part of it to give me a list of combination of numbers that fullfils
`1<= A<=B<=C<=D<=E<=F<=N` where `N` is any integer `as small as 75` which will be taken as the input. `A B C D E F` can be `any integer` as long as it `fulfills the equality`.

I know that I can just simply just go through every combination using `brute force` but it takes to long. What I want to try to do is `split` the equality into `two separate` equalities in a way that still fulfills the original, but it would cut the run in almost half.

Comment: Do you need all of the possible combinations of A, B, C, D, E, and F?

Comment: Are `A`, `B`, `C`, etc. all random values less than `N`? If so, you can generate a sequence of six random numbers, sort them, and call them your `A`, `B`, `C`, and so on.

Comment: @PWhite Yes, I would need all he possible combinations. I plan on taking those combinations and running then through other methods to further eliminate them.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want a list of all possible combinations of `A, B, C, D, E, F` that satisfy the specified condition, you can't get more efficient than doing a brute force [backtracking search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking).

For each acceptable value of `A`: find all acceptable values of `B`, then for each of those, find for `C`... and so on.

You'll get equivalent run time with:

- divide and conquer
- dynamic programming
- greedy (which just reduces to backtracking)

(but these algorithms aren't suitable for this problem and would require contrived implementations)

Answer (score 0):

The following will only generate valid valid combinations. It might take a while for large values of N, but that is because there will be a large number of combinations that satisfy your inequality.

> N = 75;  300500200 combinations
>
> N = 100; 1609344100 combinations

```
    for(int A = 1; A <= N ; ++A) {
        for(int B = A; B <= N; ++B) {
            for(int C = B; C <= N; ++C) {
                for(int D = C; D <= N; ++D) {
                    for(int E = D; E <= N; ++E) {
                        for(int F = E; F <=N; ++F) {
                            // do whatever you want with the combo
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you downvote this answer, please provide a reason so I can improve my future answers.